# React with Typescript .filter gives me error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So, I am trying to filter data from an API, but i am new with Typescript and I cannot fix this error: `Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'string'.`

```
function App() {
  const [coins, setCoins] = useState<string>('')
  const [search, setSearch] = useState<string>('')

  useEffect(()=>{
    axios
    .get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=10&page=1&sparkline=false')
    .then(res =>{
      setCoins(res.data)
      console.log(res.data)
    })
    .catch(error=>console.log(error))
  },[]);

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value)
  }

  const filteredCoins = coins.filter((coin: any) =>
    coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
  );

  return (
    <div className='coin-app'>
      <div className='coin-search'>
        <h1 className='coin-text'>Search a currency</h1>
        <form>
          <input
            className='coin-input'
            type='text'
            onChange={handleChange}
            placeholder='Search'
          />
        </form>
      </div>
      {filteredCoins.map((coin: any) => {
        return (
          <Coin
            key={coin.id}
            name={coin.name}
            price={coin.current_price}
            symbol={coin.symbol}
            marketcap={coin.total_volume}
            volume={coin.market_cap}
            image={coin.image}
            priceChange={coin.price_change_percentage_24h}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Could someone help? I tried to make the useState an array, but it still gives me this error. I am very confused to be honest.

this is the line:

```
const filteredCoins = coins.filter((coin: any) =>
```

Comment: That's because filter is an array method not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `coins` as a `string`:

```
const [coins, setCoins] = useState<string>('')
```

and then expect it to be an array here:

```
const filteredCoins = coins.filter((coin: any) =>
```

If you want the `coins` state to be an array of objects, then you have to declare it as such.

```
interface Coin {
  name: string
}
const [coins, setCoins] = useState<Coin[]>([])
```

And now you would filter it like so:

```
const filteredCoins = coins.filter((coin) =>
  coin.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
);
```

Note, you don't need to manually set a type for `coin` here. Typescript knows what type is in the array, so it will set `coin` to the correct type without your help.